# How do you make the Windows Components option appear in Setup Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2003, unattended

Supposedly there is a "Windows Components" option under Advanced Settings when you run the Setup Manager (included in the \Tools\Deploy.cab from a Windows 2003 CD).

I can't get this to show up.

Is there a special trick?

Here is a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

When I run it, it looks exactly the same except there is no "Windows Components" option above Telephony.

Comment: What OS are you running setupmanager on?

Comment: I think it was Windows Server 2003 R2...but open to seeing it work on ANY OS.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of searching on this for you and turned up exactly nothing. Perhaps n-lite can help? Its for building custom or slipstreamed installs, but it may accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't get it to show up in the GUI but the next best thing is to control those from the unattended.txt or the winbom.ini directly after saving from Setup Manager.  Once you've done your first unattended.txt you likely will use it as a jumping off point for all future customization and won't go back to Setup Manager which only supports a subset of what you can do in the config files.

Example:
`[Components]

AccessOpt = On

Appsrv_console = Off

Aspnet = Off

BitsServerExtensionsISAPI = On

BitsServerExtensionsManager = On`

Search the ref.chm Help file included in deploy.cab for "components section" for a list of all options and details of each.

Also be sure you are using the SP2 version of the deploy.cab

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93f20bb1-97aa-4356-8b43-9584b7e72556&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeah I know about that option; I was trying to get the actual GUI to work so I could figure out what the "short name" was for a particular component.

Comment: Is that link what you want it to be? I think that's just sysprep. The link for the full SP1 deploy.cab is here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a34edcf2-ebfd-4f99-bbc4-e93154c332d6 I can't find an sp2 deploy.cab.

Comment: @MikeBaz The link I proivded is 2007 SP2 deploy.cab.  Your link is SP1 from 2005.